# sql select with argument which can be NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is the best way to have a select query which has an argument which can be NULL depending on some variable in the program?

I can think of two solutions (pseudocode):

```
bool valueIsNull;
int value;

query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field ";

if (valueIsNull)
{
  query += "IS NULL";
}
else
{
  query += "= ?";
}
statement st = sql.prepare(query);

if (!valueIsNull)
{
  st.bind(0, value);
}
```

or

```
bool valueIsNull;
int value;

query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = ? OR (? IS NULL AND field IS NULL)";
statement st = sql.prepare(query);
if (valueIsNull)
{
  st.bindNull(0);
  st.bindNull(1);
}
else
{
  st.bind(0, value);
  st.bind(1, value);
}
```

It is a lot of code for just a simple SELECT statement and I find it just ugly and unclear.

The cleanest way would be something like:

```
bool valueIsNull;
int value;

query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = ?";   // <-- this does not work
statement st = sql.prepare(query);
st.bind(0, value, valueIsNull);  // <-- this works
```

Obviously this does not work. But is there a clean way to handle this?

I do not think it matter much but I am using C++, cppdb and postgresql.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your first or second example.

Comment: @mellamokb: I know both examples work but my problem is that in the first example the query differs between the two cases so it adds more complexity if I want to reuse the prepared statements. (especially when there more arguments which might be NULL). In the second case the SQL is more complex and I have to bind the same variable twice. For larger queries I find it becomes messy and obscure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Postgresql (but I believe not standard) you can use

```
SELECT * from some_table where field IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ?;
```

`IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`, unlike plain =, is true when both sides are NULL.

Comment: The issue with this, is that it won't use an index on `field`.

Comment: Next time I should check Google first. `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM` is standard SQL, although I didn't check which DBs (other then Postgres) are known to support it.

Comment: @Denis, I don't see why that would be so. NULL values are indexable.

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus the issue is that a query plan may not know which index to use and might try to create a "best of both worlds" plan to compromise between the two. This is why Gail Shaw recommends dynamic SQL and Erland Sommarskog uses `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`

Comment: @Matthew PK. That's possibly true with _any_ prepared query; it isn't special for `IS DISTINCT FROM`. If `field` is indexed, my guess is the optimizer will pick the index for this query unless the distribution of values at the time stats were last analyzed suggests not to use it, nulls or not. AFAICT from PG archives, this issue came up around the release of 8.2, some time ago now. Maybe someone will make a dummy table and actually test the query plan. It's true that the cost of recompiling/repreparing this query is probably small, but not having to repeat the param reduces mishap likelihood.

Comment: @Andrew: try it with explain. Postgres before 9.0 won't use an index in this case. (I haven't tested in 9.0.)

Comment: Postgres 9.0.1 does not use the index, even though it will use the index for an IS NULL query. Strikes me as making the `IS DISTINCT` construction useless, even if it does make for prettier code.

Comment: For now I think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

As you've noted, the main problem with this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = ? OR (? IS NULL AND field IS NULL)
```

is that it is actually two parameters which need to be bound.

You can get around that with a (should be fairly portable) construct like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
INNER JOIN (SELECT ? AS param1 /* FROM DUAL */) AS params
    ON 1 = 1
WHERE field = param1
    OR COALESCE(param1, field) IS NULL
```

Comment: I like this one because it is portable.